# Problems of hidden-surface removal when OpenGL is running in child window

Tags: winapi, opengl, 3d

I'm currently trying to draw a quadratic surface with openGL.When using a single window,my program can work well.Now I need a control panel so I create two windows,one is the frame window ,the other is the child window in which OpenGL runs.But the is something wrong with hidden-surface removal when openGL runs in the child window while this problem does not exist if I use single window.I didn't change the drawing function,just get the dc of child window and set the rc.Here is the code.Thanks for help.

```
#include <windows.h> //Windows header
#include <gl\glut.h>                                    //glut
#include <gl\glaux.h>                                   //glaux
#define hID 6310                                        //ID of child window

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc   (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;
LRESULT CALLBACK OpenProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;

TCHAR       szChildClass[] = TEXT ("OpenGL");     //child window class name
TCHAR       szAppName[] = TEXT ("Frame");         //frame window class name
HWND        hwndopen;                             //child window
handle
HWND        hwnd;                                 //frame window handle
MSG         msg ;                                 //message structure
HDC         hdc = NULL;                           //device context used in child window
HGLRC       hrc = NULL;                           //rendering context
HINSTANCE   hInstance;                            //application instance
GLuint      PixelFormat;                                //pixformat
BOOL        active=TRUE;                           
BOOL        keys[256];
float       rquad[3]={0,0,0};                     //angle of rotate    
// pfd Tells Windows How We Want Things To Be
static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd={
sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
1,PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW|
PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL|
PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
PFD_TYPE_RGBA,  
16,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0,0,0,0, 0, 0, 0,
16,
0,
0,
PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
0,
0, 0, 0 
};

/* Here I draw a color cube and I draw black line in every  edge
of the cube,the I draw 3 color lines to show x,y,z coordinate
axis*/
int DrawGLScene(void)                                   
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
glLoadIdentity();                                   
glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-10.0f);                     
glRotatef(rquad[0],1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                 
glRotatef(rquad[1],0.0f,1.0f,0.0f); 
glRotatef(rquad[2],0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);                 
glBegin(GL_QUADS);                                  
glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);              
glColor3f(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f);                      
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                      
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);                      
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);                      
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);              
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);                      
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glEnd();                                            


glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);              
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);              
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);              
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);              
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                  
glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);             
glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);             
glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);                
glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);                
glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);               
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);             
glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);                
glEnd();    
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  
glVertex3f( 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
glEnd();    
return TRUE;                                        
}


BOOL InitGL(void)                                       //init opengl
{
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            // Enable Smooth Shading
glClearColor(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.5f);
   glClearDepth(1.0f);                              glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                         glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
   return TRUE;
}

// resize the opengl scene in child window
void ReSizeGLScene(int width, int height)
{
 if (height==0)   //avoid zero to be the divisor 
                            {
    height=1;
}
glViewport(0,0,(int)width,(int)height);         
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                        
glLoadIdentity();                                   
gluPerspective(45.0f,(float)width/(float)height,0.1f,100.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                         
glLoadIdentity();                               
}



int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{


WNDCLASS     wndclass ;
BOOL         flag=TRUE;
hInstance    = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
InitGL();

wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0 ;
wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0 ;
wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))                                  
{
MessageBox(NULL,"窗口类注册失败","演示程序 ",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return 0;
}
wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = OpenProc ;
wndclass.cbWndExtra    = sizeof (long) ;
wndclass.hIcon         = NULL ;
wndclass.hbrBackground = NULL;
wndclass.lpszClassName = szChildClass ;

if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))                                  
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"子窗口类注册失败","演示程序",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return 0;
}

if(!(hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName, TEXT ("Frisa"),
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL)))
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"窗口创建失败","演示程序",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return FALSE;                           
}

ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;

while (flag)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message==WM_QUIT)           
        {
            if (!UnregisterClass(szChildClass,hInstance))           
            {
                MessageBox(NULL,"子窗口类注销失败","演示程序",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                hInstance=NULL;                                 
            }

            if (!UnregisterClass(szAppName,hInstance))          
            {
                MessageBox(NULL,"窗口类注销失败","演示程序",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                hInstance=NULL;                             
            }
            flag=FALSE;
        }
        else                                    
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);             
            DispatchMessage(&msg);              
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (active && !DrawGLScene())   // Active?  Was There A Quit Received?
        {
            flag=FALSE;                         // ESC or DrawGLScene Signalled A Quit
        }
        else                                    // Not Time To Quit, Update Screen
        {

            SwapBuffers(hdc);                   // Swap Buffers (Double Buffering)
        }
        if(keys[VK_RIGHT]){rquad[0]+=0.12;}
        if(keys[VK_LEFT]){rquad[0]=0;rquad[1]=0;rquad[2]=0;}
        if(keys[VK_UP]){rquad[1]+=0.12;}
        if(keys[VK_DOWN]){rquad[2]+=0.12;}
    }
}

return msg.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

int   cxBlock, cyBlock;

switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE :
    if(!(hwndopen= CreateWindow (szChildClass, NULL,
        WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        hwnd,(HMENU)(hID),
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong (hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL)))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"子窗口创建失败","演示程序",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 0;                               
    }
    if (!(hdc=GetDC(hwndopen)))                         
    {               
        MessageBox(NULL,"设备描述表创建失败","演示程序",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    if (!(PixelFormat=ChoosePixelFormat(hdc,&pfd)))
    {               
        MessageBox(NULL,"未找到匹配的像素格式","演示程序",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    if(!SetPixelFormat(hdc,PixelFormat,&pfd))   
    {               
        MessageBox(NULL,"设置像素格式失败","演示程序",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    if (!(hrc=wglCreateContext(hdc)))           
    {               
        MessageBox(NULL,"获取渲染描述表失败","演示程序",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    if(!wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hrc))                
    {               
        MessageBox(NULL,"渲染描述表激活失败","演示程序",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 0;
    }
    return 0 ;

case WM_ACTIVATE:                           // Watch For Window Activate Message
    // LoWord Can Be WA_INACTIVE, WA_ACTIVE, WA_CLICKACTIVE,
    // The High-Order Word Specifies The Minimized State Of The Window Being Activated Or Deactivated.
    // A NonZero Value Indicates The Window Is Minimized.
    if ((LOWORD(wParam) != WA_INACTIVE) && !((BOOL)HIWORD(wParam)))
        active=TRUE;                        // Program Is Active
    else
        active=FALSE;                       // Program Is No Longer Active
    return 0;                               // Return To The Message Loop

case WM_SIZE :
    cxBlock = LOWORD (lParam);
    cyBlock = HIWORD (lParam);
    MoveWindow (hwndopen,
        5,5,
        (int)(cxBlock*0.80),(int)(cyBlock*0.98), TRUE) ;
    ReSizeGLScene((int)(cxBlock*0.80),(int)(cyBlock*0.97));
    return 0 ;

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN :
    MessageBeep (0) ;
    return 0 ;

case WM_KEYDOWN:                
    keys[wParam] = TRUE;                
    return 0;                       

case WM_KEYUP:                              
    keys[wParam] = FALSE;
    return 0;

case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    return 0;

case WM_DESTROY :
    if (hrc)                                            
    {
        if (!wglMakeCurrent(hdc,NULL))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,"DC和RC关联解除失败","演示程序",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }

        if (!wglDeleteContext(hrc)) 
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,"RC释放失败","演示程序",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }

        hrc=NULL;
    }

    if (!DestroyWindow(hwnd))   
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"窗口句柄释放失败","演示程序",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        hwnd=NULL;  
    }

    PostQuitMessage (0) ;
    return 0 ;

}
return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
  }

LRESULT CALLBACK OpenProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
                       WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

ADDITION

My aim is to paint a clolor cube in the child window with OpenGL.The size of the child window is about 0.8 times the frame window's size.I will add a control panel in the rest of area of the frame window. My program can draw a color cube .But the problem is I can see all the 6 faces,and all the 12 edges of the cube.I'm not sure but it looks like the hidden-surface removal failed.

Here I provide a link to the image of the result.
http://svgeqg.blu.livefilestore.com/y1p_TRCQ495hxOztZy3oi5qZiDPdN9hQil0KLTY9I-7fFfqCuVr_FiyJ-dIlflN5eHCMqZo5smpUwTaFDxAelq_rjO5hTU5kVzS/colorcube.JPG?psid=1

Comment: What something is wrong with the hidden-surface removal?

Comment: Could you possibly make a simpler example and/or explain more precisely what the result is and what you expected it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem,it's about the location of the OpenGL initialization.The initializationmust be after the creation of the child window in which OpenGL runs.In the above code，I init OpenGL at the beginning of winmain() function ,but the child window does not exist at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Add CS_OWNDC to your windowclass, otherwise a embedded window will share its DC with its parent. OpenGL windows should always get their own DC, so for OpenGL Window class:

```
wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
```

**EDIT due to comment**

I also don't see the PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR being actually set. Could you please show the code where you select the one PFD most closely resembling your request (API calls `ChoosePixelFormat`, `DescribePixelFormat`) and setting it on your window (`SetPixelFormat` API call). Also for debugging you should dump the PFD the system returned upon your request.

In addition to that, windows using OpenGL should be created with window styles `WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`

Comment: I set the PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR at the top,and all the operations of PixelFormat is implemented just follow the creation of child window.I have solved the problem,it's about the location of the OpenGL initialization.Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Frisa: It would be nice if you'd answer yourself with the solution, and accept this answer, so that people know this question has been solved and can learn from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find I have a Low-level errors committed.The initialization of OpenGL should be after the creation of the child window,but I put it at top,so it does not work.